# IOS app crashes on keyboard press

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I get the following error when I try to enter text into a text field:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

This happens when I try to type in some text into a textfield. I'm testing this on an empty view inside a view controller. I have created the IBOutlet for the text field and set its delegate to my controller. Not sure what I'm missing.

**UPDATE**
So when I try this on a new storyboard by adding a new view controller and just one text field, it does not throw this exception. Perhaps something wrong with this storyboard?

Comment: Can you provide more code on the delegate methods you overrode for UITextField.

Comment: So I have the IBOutlet in the .h: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

Comment: And in the implementation: 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [[self textField] setText:@"whatever"];
}

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Solution**:

My issue was caused because I inadvertently clicked on the Key Commands controls in the attribute inspector. I did not create any commands, but having and empty entry caused any input into a textField to crash. The issue would only reproduce itself on the device and not in the simulator.

Look at all of your View Controllers' Attribute Inspectors for :

[[image: Key Commands brick in the Attribute Inspector[1]]

and remove that empty "Enter action below" entry.

Hopefully this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post code, I can only tell you what the error message means in the most common case.

It appears you are pulling items out of a collection, since that is the most common place an `NSNull` is used. You may be doing something else with `NSNull` that we cannot see, with no code to reference of course.

You are trying to get the length of something that is presumably intended to be an `NSString` but at runtime it is in fact `NSNull`, which does not have the `length`method defined. You will need to check if the object is `NSNull` and do something else, since NSNull will refuse to call undefined selectors.

```
if (text == [NSNull null]) {
  // do something different
} else {
    text.length; // call methods on NSString
}
```

If you are expecting `NSNull` to behave like `nil`, they are both very different. Nil will not throw an error on methods it doesn't recognize, it will just no-op, while the NSNull object(which is actually a singleton/flyweight) will crash. You will always need to check for `NSNull` if you are using them in arrays, dictionaries, etc. If you are using `NSNull` for another purpose, consider using nil instead.

Answer (score 0):

you call a Nil object's method length. make sure your viewController outlet is link to you textField and @synthesize youTextField

Comment: nil is not NSNull. Also, synthesize is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks. I should go to check how to use them